# Set my application title in the Contacts Quickbadge

Tags: android, xmpp, quickcontactbadge, quickcontact

[image]

I am using the third party Jabber Client(XABBER). I was able to integrate it into my application, but in the QuickContactbadge, it is showing the application name as Jabber.

I do not know where to find the code of changing the name.
I have verified manifest file. And there is no issue with it.

Could anybody please suggest which could be the Activity or Service which will be setting the app name as Jabber as shown in the screenshot.